# (Three time printing) External native build android studio (Android NDK)

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, android-build

When I want to try compile my Android NDK project, the project will be compile three times in one time, why?

BUILD.GRADLE :

```
[https://pastebin.com/vTwDbRpb]
```

The `CmakeLists` which will be call -->

```
[https://pastebin.com/HX7RBB4k]
```

But these files will be run three times as well, I don't know what is going on?

You can see the output on the pic bellow :

[image: output android studio]

If someone have an idea, I will be very grateful.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably build 3 different flavours (build types): **debug**, **release**, and **customDebugType**. All are explicitly declared in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Got it, that's this !! really easy thing, sorry for bothering and +1 for your answer which works well.